# Choose the first non-null field for each record in ServiceNow

Tags: servicenow

How to create a view in ServiceNow that combines multiple columns (same data type) into one by picking the first non-null value? Note that it should not actually modify the underlying data.

After a search of the documentation I thought I had an answer with function fields, but GlideFunction doesn't seem to have nvl/coalesce as a function. The functionality called coalesce in ServiceNow seems to relate to importing/permanently modifying data only.

An example would be if you have employee and department, both of which have a location field. Show the employee's location unless it is null, otherwise show the employee's department's location.

In standard SQL, I would do it like this:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS (
  SELECT COALESCE(employee.location,department.location) AS location
  FROM employee JOIN department
  ON employee.department_id = department.department_id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned how you are going to query this view. SNOW does not give us control over selection while designing views like the standard SQL.

Use GlideRecord to conditionally select the columns based on nullability.

Comment: "Use GlideRecord to conditionally select the columns based on nullability." Can you elaborate on that? -- I'll fess up, this is a second hand question. I was the phone-a-friend option for my friend who is fighting with ServiceNow. I've never actually had my hands on the keyboard with SNOW, but usually I can solve his questions just based on being good with searching and reading quickly. (I am just a normal developer, so that is like 90% of what I do all day anyway.)